# MySQLで動画データ型を扱えますか？

Tags: mysql

MySQLに動画を組み込むことは可能ですか？ またその際のインサートの仕方は他と同じですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく普通の整数や文字列のようにカラムに動画のデータをそのまま入れることを想像なさっているのかと思いますが、通常そのようなことは行いません。SQL で動画のデータについて何かしら検索することは通常無いからです。少なくとも MySQL 8.0 の時点ではマルチメディア用のデータ型は用意されていません: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html。

MySQL で動画を取り扱う方法のひとつとしては、何かしらストレージに別途動画を保存しておいて、そこへのパスを文字列として DB に保存するやり方があります。たとえば Amazon S3 に動画を保存し、その URI を保存する、などです。

Comment: たとえば Amazon S3 に動画を保存し、その URI を保存する、などです。 なるほどです ありがとうございます YouTube 等 もそうしてるのですか ？ 独自のサーバーだとはおもいますが

Comment: YouTube だとそもそも MySQL を使っているのかというところから不明です。

Comment: そうなんですか サーバーの性能としていちばん優秀なのは YouTube だとおもっていますが AWS My SQL の コンビ いがい に なにかおもいあたるものはありますか ？

Comment: Google Cloud Platform（GCP）についてお調べください。また当然、オンプレミスな環境を使っている可能性もあります。YouTube の使っている技術についてはこのご質問の内容からはオフトピックになってくるので、コメントでなくて別途ご質問いただけると助かります。

Comment: わかりました ありがとうございます